# Cordova/PhoneGap app icons/splashscreens in config.xml missing

Tags: cordova

#### Structure

I currently have a structure like so:

```
project/
    www/
        images/
            icon.png
    config.xml
```

Inside config.xml:

```
<icon src="www/images/icon.png" />
```

I use `cordova build` to populate the `platforms/` directory (it doesn't exist on initial checkout of the project's repository).

The contents of `www/` are successfully copied to each platform directory.

#### Problem

On launch of the app, the icon on the home screen appears to be a white placeholder. I guess this means the icon didn't load correctly.

Do I have the path wrong? Does the build process not copy it to the right place? What other explanation could there be?

Comment: Are you using splashscreen plugin?

Comment: No, right now I'm just trying to get the icon working before I go anywhere near splash screens. So it shouldn't matter that it isn't installed, unless for some insane reason icons depend on it too.

Comment: Also note that it does remove the cordova default icon, so that means it has detected I have specified one, but just doesn't display it (instead a white placeholder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have explained is one of the way of setting the app icon, and it works fine for Android and WP8 platforms, but not for iOS.

Since each device has their specific icon size, so device will not support those icons whose size are lesser (it may support bigger sizes) to specific size.

I guess the size of your icon is not appropriate for your iOS device on which you are testing the app. For example if you are testing your app in iphone 6s Plus then size of your icon should be 80x80 or next above size mention in the bellow link. 
you can follow the following link for correct icon size for your device or other ways to set the app icon :
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

Other way:
 you can add following line to your config.xml file :

```
 <platform name="ios">
        <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
    </platform>`enter code here`
```

Here you should follow the same path, size and naming convention.

Comment: It would seem you are correct about the icons, however the splash screen still uses the default cordova image. I followed the launch image sizes which apple display on their current docs (1080x1920, 750x1334, 640x1136, 2048x2732, 1536x2048). But no luck... (and I did install the plugin now)

Comment: Yes, a few resolutions which iOS uses were missing :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Need not to write  tag in config.html. Just replace default `icon.png` file with your `icon.png` in "res" folder.

[image]